# How to generate JavaScript DocFX documentation in an MVC project?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-mvc, docfx

I've successfully generated a documentation website with DocFX for C# of apps written with .NET Core MVC and Razor Pages. The [DocFX guide](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/universalreference/gen_doc_for_js.html) says it also supports generating API documentation for JavaScript. I want to do that for files in wwwroot folder of my MVC projects.

Right now, I'm just trying to generate the YAML files mentioned in section *2.2 General Metadata* of the linked documentation. I created the `node2doxfx.json` file:

```
{
  "source": {
    "include": [ "C:/Users/username/Source/Repos/Tracker/Scan/wwwroot/js" ]
  },
  "destination": "C:/Users/username/source/repos/Tracker/Documentation"
}
```

Then I ran the following command in the terminal:

```
node 'C:\Users\username\source\repos\Tracker\Scan\wwwroot\js\site.js' node2docfx.json
```

I get no error in the terminal when executing this command, but I don't see any files generated in `.../Tracker/Documentation` destination folder.

Where is my mistake and how can I get this to work?

Comment: I also encountered this problem, I think it may be a problem with `Yaml` validation. In .net core, Docfx seems to only recognize controllers and models by default. The `metadata/dest` in the docfx.json file can set the location where the `yml` file is generated in .net core (only controllers and models).